# Animate UITableViewCell depending on the position of the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to animate a UITableViewCell depending on the position of the cell during scrolling. 
My UITableViewCell contains an image which is shown in an UIImage class. The height of the original image is higher than the height of the visible frame. During scrolling the image should scroll inside the UIImage.

Most tutorials or StackOverflow questions/answers suggest to use animateWithDuration. That's not what I want to do. The scrolling inside the UIImage class depends on the scrolling speed of the TableView.

I've added some images to illustrate what I mean.

Any idea?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know how smooth it will be, but you should take a look at the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to know what happens to your `UITableView`, and create a method in your custom cell to do your animation. Call this method on the cells from the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods

Comment: That might work. I'll try this. Thank you.

Comment: This could help you: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/05/parallax-scrolling-collectionview/

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the effect I try to implement.